# External USB Hard Drive Disconnects When Unused

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

I have a "TerraMaster D2-310 USB Type C External Hard Drive RAID Enclosure USB3.1 (Gen1)" that works fine, except if it not used for a while it becomes invisible to the PC, even if the PC is in use. If I turn it off and then on, it is visible again.

How can I prevent this? I want it to be accessible at all times if powered.

Using Windows 11, latest patches.

Unit shows up in "Device Manager" as "TDAS TerraMaster SCSI Disk Device". Says I have the latest drivers installed.

Comment: In Device Manager, right-click the device, select Properties, tab Power Management, uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" and click OK. Reboot to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have that option. Might depend on the driver?

Comment: (1) Do my advice for the disks inside the enclosure. (2) Try [this advice](https://forum.terra-master.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=86&t=3840).

Comment: Thanks! Will that keep ALL my hard drives forever spinning, or just the NAS? I don't want 
 to have the PC hard drives on at all times. I would just like the NAS to be spinning at all times if it's powered on.

Comment: I assume you refer to number (2). Note that PC internal drives cannot really be turned off.

Comment: For (1), I don't see the disks inside the enclosure as separate disks. I am using RAID1, and I only see the the whole device as "TDAS TerraMaster SCSI Disk Device". I don't know where to view/access the individual hard drives mounted in the enclosure.

Comment: Right - Windows hides the disks in a raid. Try in Device Manager > Universal Serial Bus Controllers, to select all USB Root Hubs and in Power Management uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".